# mvc chrome browser caches view result

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, browser-cache, outputcache

I've a simple question about unexpected view caching in chrome. I've Asp.Net MVC web-app. On my search page I've a reset button which does a page refresh using a javascript function (simple window.location.href logic). All is good and working fine in IE as well as FF.

When I started testing in google Chrome I'm getting some unexpected view caching - in short the browser is showing cached view result.

I tried the following on top of my action but no effect in chrome -

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
```

A simple F5 will also refresh/reset the page to original state but my js function based refresh is not working in Chrome. Any idea?

Extra: Does chrome understand table / div width in % done via style or inline attribute? I got some unexpected hiccups while testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this was long ago. Now, I've partial postback using AJAX (and I use jQuery.forms.js so I can do `$(frmId).ajaxForm({ ...}))`

So, I don't have to wait / rely on the browser to refresh. Now, the content of my Grid is replaced directly with what is being returned from my partial view.

Also see, [more processing upon success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call) & [extended validation beforeSubmit](http://www.chrillo.info/2008/10/14/jquery-ajaxform-and-validate-with-ajaxsubmit/)